# Word VBA Creation Date as Just date and No Time

Tags: vba, properties, ms-word

Trying to get the creation date of a document with just the date and no time (this is to select all documents in a folder that were created on a given day).

I can get the date and time the documents were created but not just the date!
Is there a way to do this in Word VBA?

Currently using the following line of code for this:

```
       intDate = wdDocTgt.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Creation Date")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rounding (actually just take the integer part):

```
intDate = int(wdDocTgt.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Creation Date"))
```

Remember, dates and times are just numbers. Everything is stored in days, which means time is the fraction part. Removing the fractions removes the time.

Comment: This worked perfectly. +1 and marked as answered - very clear and straight forward solution very easy for me to understand.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help. :)

Comment: Is there a way I could check the document create date is after a date time - e.g midday and before 11:59:00 the following day? I'm trying this now but it's not working

Comment: Hmm, `intDate < dtYourdate+0.5` or something similar should work. If it does not, try asking another question. Or `dateadd("n",60*12-1,dtYourDate+1)` Dateadd function is your friend. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
? VarType(ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date"))
 7 
? vbDate
 7 
? Int((ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date")))
16-07-27
```